# Bootstrap Navbar toggle will not expand

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not able to find where and what I am doing wrong here.
I have looked for the answer and also tried the using a solution for the same issue as mine but none of the previous solutions are working... Please help me out.

The toggle bar does not expand when clicked.
Here is the link to my files:

[My Files](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3efTmJwuFDQWjkxS2VHYktzWVE)

Comment: have you added jquery.min in your footer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the toggle to work you will need to include jQuery at the bottom of your body.

here is the script:

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Cheers friend, the script did wonders... Thank You.

Comment: @varun 

Glad I could help!